# 3D terrain generation with overhangs/caves

Tags: procedural-generation

3D terrain with 2D noise function as heightmap is kind of 'easy'. Make a plane and adjust height based on the noise.

How would one start working on 3D terrain with overhangs/caves?

There are some older topics (for example related to Minecraft) on the thema, but non of them cover overhangs and in general techniques that can be applied to heightmap generated terrain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate caves that resemble those of Minecraft?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33590/how-to-generate-caves-that-resemble-those-of-minecraft)

Comment: See also: [3D Cube World Level Generation](http://accidentalnoise.sourceforge.net/minecraftworlds.html) and [Cellular Automata Method for Generating Random Cave-Like Levels](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Cellular_Automata_Method_for_Generating_Random_Cave-Like_Levels), and I guess [Marching cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes).

Comment: Have you consulted other methods of representing terrain, like [the vector field displacement used to create overhangs in Halo Wars](https://gdcvault.com/play/1277/HALO-WARS-The-Terrain-of)?

Comment: @DMGregory looks promising. However this game is more handcrafted, where project I'm working on is infinite worlds.

Comment: There's nothing about a vector field that makes it suited only to hand-crafting — folks generate vector fields of various types all the time.

Comment: @DMGregory ok. I try to study it more. Maybe you can point out more resources, also on caves?